# Refer to Index in Creating Data Frame R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have variables v1,v2,etc and I want to create a dataframe.

I want to avoid doing:

```
df <-data.frame(v1,v2,...)
```

I would like to refer to the index in each of the variables and do something like:

```
for (i in 1:n){
df <-data.frame(v[i])
}
```

or do a max and min:

```
df <-data.frame(v1 to vn)
```

I just can't figure out what the proper syntax is.

Comment: The question is why you have these variables to begin with. It's good practice to store data in bigger data structures such as lists and data.frames from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
as.data.frame(mget(paste0("v", 1:n)))
```

---

```
v1 <- 1:3
v2 <- 2:4
v3 <- 3:5

as.data.frame(mget(paste0("v", 1:3)))
#   v1 v2 v3
# 1  1  2  3
# 2  2  3  4
# 3  3  4  5
```

Comment: a similar followup. Can I refer to observations in another dataframe for the range? I'm trying to do the following:

rowdata<-as.data.frame(mget(paste0(data[5,1], data[9,ncol(data)]:data[9,2] )))